# pandas: tricking left join in python

Tags: python, pandas

please how should i do to get the result below. if the cod of df_1 exists in df_2 then i should add the row as explained in my code below.

```
data1 = {'date': ['2021-06', '2021-06', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07'], 'cod': ['12', '12', '14', '15', '15', '18'], 'Zone': ['LA', 'NY', 'LA', 'NY', 'PARIS', 'PARIS'], 'Revenue_Radio': [10, 20, 30, 50, 40, 10]}  


df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) 

data2 = {'date': ['2021-06', '2021-06', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-08'], 'cod': ['12', '14', '15', '15', '18'], 'Zone': ['PARIS', 'NY', 'LA', 'NY', 'NY'], 'Revenue_Str': [10, 20, 30, 50, 5]}  

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

the expected output is

```
data_result = {'date': ['2021-06', '2021-06', '2021-06', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07','2021-07'], 'cod': ['12', '12', '12', '14', '14', '15', '15', '15', '18'], 'Zone': ['LA', 'NY', 'PARIS','LA', 'NY', 'NY', 'PARIS', 'LA', 'PARIS'], 'Revenue_Radio': [10, 20, 0,  30, 0, 50, 40, 0, 10], 'Revenue_Str': [0, 0, 10,0, 20, 50, 0, 30, 0]}    
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data_result)
```

Comment: It seems oupur join by first 3 columns

Comment: @jezrael can you help more please? i saw the link that you added but was not able to solve it .. Thank youu ^^

Comment: Can you try `df_1.merge(df_2, on=['date','cod','Zone'], how='outer').fillna(0)` ?

Comment: can't do it because if i have this row in df_2  '2021-08', '18',  'PARIS',  5 
  and not exist in df_1 i want that this row will not appear in my resulting dataframe . Hope that im clear . Thank you

Comment: @jezrael do you see what i mean?

Comment: Can you EDIt data for see, why is not possible use solution above?

Comment: It's done !! when i tried your solution i got row with cod=18 what is was not expected in my results.

Comment: i don't want that row with cod=18 appear since is not in the df_1. Hope im clear now

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join by `date` and `cod` first, and then outer join with replace missing values:

```
df22 = df_2.merge(df_1[['date','cod']].drop_duplicates(), on=['date','cod'])
df = (df_1.merge(df22, on=['date','cod','Zone'], how='outer')
          .fillna(0)
          .sort_values(['date','cod'], ignore_index=True))
print (df)
      date cod   Zone  Revenue_Radio  Revenue_Str
0  2021-06  12     LA           10.0          0.0
1  2021-06  12     NY           20.0          0.0
2  2021-06  12  PARIS            0.0         10.0
3  2021-07  14     LA           30.0          0.0
4  2021-07  15     NY           50.0         50.0
5  2021-07  15  PARIS           40.0          0.0
6  2021-07  15     LA            0.0         30.0
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but with this solution i got either cod=18 for 08-2021 and cod=18 for 07-2021. My expected result should in this case contain only the cod=18 of 07-2021. Thank you in advance . I udated my original post

Comment: question please ? with you solution im still having this row among the resulting dataframe **2021-06  14  NY** do you see the cause please?

Comment: i adde & (df_2['date'].isin(df_1['date'])) to your code but im still gotting 2021-06 14 NY. Do you know how to do please? thank you

Comment: @tamo007 - Sorry, I was offline. Answer was edited.